# Matlab - Generating multiple matrices by looping

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a vector with +16M data, and I've got to transform it in 101 matrices of 401x401 elements each. I know how to create such matrices independently (writing a loop for each one of them) but I think there must be some way to create all of them in using two or more loops. The problem is, I don't know exactly how to do this.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
data=load('file.dat');%This file contains 3 columns of data, I only need the first one
var=data(:,1);
p=401;%Size of the matrices
for n=0:400
    mat1(n+1,:)=var(p*n+1:p*(n+1),:);
end
```

This code would create the first 401x401 matrix. By changing the indices, I could (individually) create the rest, but I would prefer to add another loop (or loops) to create them automatically instead of repeating this code a hundred times.

Comment: Have you thought about using `reshape` (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to bring the vector into a form of 401 x 401 x 101?

Comment: This would be a great solution, thanks! However, I don't know how to plot such a variable!

Comment: `n = 4; 
l = 8; 
vec = 1:n*n*l;
mat = reshape(vec, n, n, l); `
replace vec with your data, n with 401 and l with 101 and see what happens ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `mat = vec2mat(vec,matcol)` converts the vector `vec` into a matrix with `matcol` columns, creating one row at a time. If the length of `vec` is not a multiple of `matcol`, then extra zeros are placed in the last row of mat. The matrix mat has `ceil(length(vec)/matcol)` rows.
See also the [manual entry](http://de.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, this data were taken by rows and I needed to respect this order when creating my matrices. Is there any way I could plot (3D graphic or such) the resulting 401x401x101 elements variable?

Comment: You have three dimensions of arguments? You can only plot 3D plots from R^2 to R  with commands like`surf`.

Comment: You may go through all the 101 samples and for each matrix `mat`, you can call `surf(mat)`.